# Shortcode showing as plain text in get_the_content()

Tags: wordpress

I am using a video in a post content.And i am calling that post content outside the loop using post id. But instead of showing a iFrame its showing embed plain text like this

```
[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ror4P1UAv_g[/embed]   Course Description Satellite Engineering introduces students to subsystem design in engineering spacecraft. The course presents characteristic subsystems,
```

I am using :

```
<?php echo get_the_content( null, false, 11118 ) ?>
```

i also tried

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_the_content( null, false, 11118 ) ); ?>
```

But then the shortcode text also disappears.
How can i show the video?

Comment: Try using `the_content()` instead of `echo get_the_content()` and do not use any parameters.

Comment: @rank I used but no luck.Also i need to use post id cause im using it outside loop, in another page

Comment: does the gutenberg editor recognize it as a shortcode and put it in a block for this?

Answer (score 0):

#### From the [Embed Shortcode Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embed_Shortcode):

> Note: This shortcode isn't enabled until 'the_content' filter has been processed at least once. If you need to run this shortcode before or without The Loop and aren't using the_content() you'll need to call the following method with the content which contains the [embed] shortcode:

`$GLOBALS['wp_embed']->run_shortcode( 'Content with [embed] shortcode' );`

In your case you can try this:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_embed']->run_shortcode( get_the_content( null, false, 11118 ) );
```